# Is focus rect drawn automatically for listbox (WC_LISTVIEW)?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, listbox

I have created a listbox similar to the code provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/create-a-list-view-control). In my UI, will the tab focus rect be automatically drawn by DefWindowProc() or do I need to take care of that ? I don't see the focus rect being drawn on tab focus.

Thanks.

```
HWND CreateListView (HWND hwndParent) 
{
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;           // Structure for control initialization.
icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

RECT rcClient;                       // The parent window's client area.

GetClientRect (hwndParent, &rcClient); 

// Create the list-view window in report view with label editing enabled.
HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, 
                                 L"",
                                 WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_LIST,
                                 0, 0,
                                 rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
                                 rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                                 hwndParent,
                                 (HMENU)IDM_CODE_SAMPLES,
                                 g_hInst,
                                 NULL); 

return (hWndListView);
}
```

Comment: There's no code at that link showing owner drawing. Are you talking about a listview (`WC_LISTVIEW`) or a listbox (`WC_LISTBOX`)? If a listview, are you talking about owner draw (with the `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style) or custom draw (by responding to the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` notification)? These details are important.

Comment: Talking about WC_LISTVIEW

Comment: So, essentially, I have a UI Dialog and adding the listview to that.

Comment: The default window procedure draws a focus rectangle for the list box item drawn by the owner in response to the WM_DRAWITEM message.

Comment: Make sure to select at least one listview item, otherwise there won't be focus rectangle visible.

Answer (score 0):

Normally,the default window procedure draws a focus rectangle for the list box item drawn by the owner in response to the `WM_DRAWITEM` message.

In [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagdrawitemstruct)

> For an empty list box or combo box, `itemID` can be -1. This allows
>   the application to draw only the focus rectangle at the coordinates
>   specified by the `rcItem` member even though there are no items in the
>   control. This indicates to the user whether the list box or combo box
>   has the focus. How the bits are set in the `itemAction` member
>   determines whether the rectangle is to be drawn as though the list box
>   or combo box has the focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using owner/custom draw then all Windows common controls will draw the focus rectangle for you automatically.

Windows 2000 (and later) hide keyboard accelerators and focus rectangles by default unless you are interacting with the window by using your keyboard.

> Windows enables applications to hide or show various features in its UI. These settings are known as [the UI state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/about-keyboard-accelerators#ui-state). The UI state includes the following settings:
>
> - focus indicators (such as focus rectangles on buttons)
> - keyboard accelerators (indicated by underlines in control labels)